# Ajax Autocomplete filling up both input fierlds witth same value, although I have implemented both functions separately with different logic

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have 2 input fields

> 1. Student Name Input Field
> 2. Group Name Input Field

I have implemented 2 different ajax logic to fetch list of students and groups for autocomplete in textboxes separately in different  tag.

But when I click one value from any autocomplete value either student list or group list, both input fields are being filled up with selected value

Image :
[Group List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fp5d.png)

Image:
[Both fields are filling up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5i9C.png)

## Code for fetch Student (JavaScript) :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#studentname").keyup(function()
            {
                var studentName = $(this).val();
                if(studentName != '')
                {
                    $.ajax({
                       url: "SearchStudent.php",
                       method: "POST",
                       data:{studentName:studentName},
                       success: function(data)
                       {
                           $('#students').fadeIn();
                           $('#students').html(data);
                       }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#students').fadeOut();
                    $('#students').html("");
                }
            });
            $(document).on('click','li',function()
            {
               $('#studentname').val($(this).text());
               $('#students').fadeOut();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

## Code for Fetch Group (JavaScript):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#groupname").keyup(function()
            {
                var groupName = $(this).val();
                if(groupName != '')
                {
                    $.ajax({
                       url: "SearchGroup.php",
                       method: "POST",
                       data:{groupName:groupName},
                       success: function(Groupdata)
                       {
                           $('#groups').fadeIn();
                           $('#groups').html(Groupdata);
                       }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#groups').fadeOut();
                    $('#groups').html("");
                }
            });
            $(document).on('click','li',function()
            {
               $('#groupname').val($(this).text());
               $('#groups').fadeOut();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

## PHP Code (SearchStudent.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "../../config/connection.php";
if(isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_POST['studentName'])
{
    $StudentName = $_POST['studentName'];

$output = '';
$searchStudent = "SELECT StudentName FROM student_details WHERE StudentName LIKE '%$StudentName%' LIMIT 10";
$searchStudentFire = mysqli_query($conn, $searchStudent);
$output = "<ul style='list-style-type: none;'>";
if(mysqli_num_rows($searchStudentFire) > 0)
{
    while($StudentList = mysqli_fetch_assoc($searchStudentFire))
    {
        $output.= "<li style='font-weight:bold; border: 1px; padding: 10px; box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px #888888;'>".$StudentList['StudentName']."</li>";
    }
}
else
{
    $output.= "<li>No Student Found</li>";
}
$output .= "</ul>";
echo $output;
}
else
{
    echo "Unautorizarion Error !!";
}
?>
```

## PHP Code (SearchGroup.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "../../config/connection.php";
if(isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_POST['groupName'])
{
    $GroupName = $_POST['groupName'];

$output = '';
$searchGroup = "SELECT GroupName FROM groups WHERE GroupName LIKE '%$GroupName%' LIMIT 10";
$searchGroupFire = mysqli_query($conn, $searchGroup);
$output = "<ul style='list-style-type: none;'>";
if(mysqli_num_rows($searchGroupFire) > 0)
{
    while($GroupList = mysqli_fetch_assoc($searchGroupFire))
    {
        $output.= "<li style='font-weight:bold; border: 1px; padding: 10px; box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px #888888;'>".$GroupList['GroupName']."</li>";
    }
}
else
{
    $output.= "<li>No Group Found</li>";
}
$output .= "</ul>";
echo $output;
}
else
{
    echo "Unautorizarion Error !!";
}
?>
```

## Input Fields & Autocomplete  area :

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="input--style-5" type="text" name="studentname" id="studentname"> <!--Student Field-->
<div style="" id="students" name="students"></div> <!--Auto Complete Area Div-->

<input autocomplete="off" class="input--style-5" type="text" id="groupname" name="groupname"><!--Group Field-->
<div id="groups" name="groups"></div><!--Autocomplete area-->
```

Comment: You miss to close (>)  input  `groupname`.  Is that a problem or just copy / paste mistake.

Comment: copy paste mistake

Comment: I have updated the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two blocks are your problem, they both respond to a click on any `li`

```
        $(document).on('click','li',function()
        {
           $('#studentname').val($(this).text());
           $('#students').fadeOut();
        });


        $(document).on('click','li',function()
        {
           $('#groupname').val($(this).text());
           $('#groups').fadeOut();
        });
```

You need to adjust your selectors to target the respective lists as follows:

```
        $(document).on('click','#students li',function()
        {
           $('#studentname').val($(this).text());
           $('#students').fadeOut();
        });


        $(document).on('click','#groups li',function()
        {
           $('#groupname').val($(this).text());
           $('#groups').fadeOut();
        });
```

Or like this:

```
        $('#students').on('click','li',function()
        {
           $('#studentname').val($(this).text());
           $('#students').fadeOut();
        });


        $('#groups').on('click','li',function()
        {
           $('#groupname').val($(this).text());
           $('#groups').fadeOut();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You selectors are not specific enough in your "on" functions. Try:

```
$(document).on('click', '#students li', function(){
    $('#studentname').val($(this).text());
    $('#students').fadeOut();
});
```

and:

```
$(document).on('click', '#groups li', function(){
    $('#groupname').val($(this).text());
    $('#groups').fadeOut();
});
```

instead. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: You have just repeated my answer

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry I started typing it before you submitted, and your answer didn't show up until I submitted. Compliments to your answer.